# Angular4 fullcalendar version mismatch

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

could somebody help to fix issue.
suddenly project compile error:

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol SystemModule in
```

/src/app/system/system.module.ts, resolving symbol SystemModule in F:/javascript/ics-frontend-angular2/src/app/system/system.module.ts
        at Error (native)

node version

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.1
node: 6.9.1
```

package.json
"ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.3.5",
how can I fix that?

full package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.2",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.4.0",
    "angular-select2-component": "^1.0.4",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "~0.9.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "angular2-select": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.0",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "ng2-stomp-service": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please ask on GitHub: https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar/issues

Comment: It's not problem in calendar dependency, post your package.json

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled "ap-angular2-fullcalendar" to version "1.3.1". It's work for me.

Command:
npm install ap-angular2-fullcalendar@1.3.1